# How do I cast a timestamp column as a MM/DD/YYYY in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to cast the results of an entire column in BigQuery in MM/DD/YYYY format

| Time_Column |
| --- |
| 2022-05-26T17:32:41.000Z |
| 2022-05-28T06:34:23.000Z |

Results:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try to use [`FORMAT_DATE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#format_date) function to make it, we can refer to this link  [Supported Format Elements For DATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements#format_elements_date_time) to use your expected date format from the datetime type.

```
SELECT FORMAT_DATE("%m/%d/%Y", Time_Column) 
FROM T
```

Comment: Hm, that's not working for me. I even tried casting it and then just got a bunch of nulls.

Getting this error: No matching signature for function FORMAT_DATE for argument types: STRING, STRING. Supported signatures: FORMAT_DATE(STRING, DATE); FORMAT_DATE(STRING, DATETIME); FORMAT_DATE(STRING, TIMESTAMP, [STRING]) at [4:3]

Comment: Wait. I got it. Converted it to a TIMESTAMP (it was a string) and that did the trick. Thank you!